# How is the splat operator understood when applied to a range expression?

Tags: ruby, splat

I found that the expression `[*1..4]` returns the same as if I would do a `(1..4).to_a`, but I don't understand the syntax here. My understanding is that `*` is - being a unary operator in this case - to be the *splat operator*, and to the right of it, we have a Range. However, if just write the expression `*1..4`, this is a syntax error, and `*(1..4)` is a syntax error too. Why does the first `[*1..4]` work and how it is understood in detail?

Comment: Btw this works fine too: `r = (1..4); [*r]`

Comment: Yes. The parenthesis are optional; you could have written `r=1..4; [*r]`, which of course is the same as my `[*1..4]`. But the array context is crucial. Just `*r` would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splat `*` converts the object to an *list of values* (usually an *argument list*) by calling its `to_a` method, so `*1..4` is equivalent to:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

On its own, the above isn't valid. But wrapped within square brackets, `[*1..4]` becomes:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Which is valid.

You could also write `a = *1..4` which is  equivalent to:

```
a = 1, 2, 3, 4
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here, the list of values becomes an array due to Ruby's [implicit array assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Implicit+Array+Assignment).

Comment: Can you do parallel assignment using `*` notation?

Comment: @SagarPandya sure, `a, b = *1..2` is equivalent to `a, b = 1, 2`